# iPhone - AudioToolbox and recording

Tags: iphone, audio-recording, audiotoolbox

In my application, I'm playing an audio using audio toolbox framework.
When its playing, how can I record the same?
I tried using AVAudioRecording by setting audio session "Play and Record". But when recording, the volume of the audio being played is getting reduced.
How can I use Audiotoolbox framework itself and record the audio?

Can some one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the AVAudioRecorder to record itself.  You can use the Audio Queue or the Audio Unit RemoteIO APIs, and capture the audio samples you are putting in the output buffers to play as you play them.

Comment: Do you know any good tutorial for using Audio Queue or Remote IO API's for recording?